# Android ListView with TextView and Spinner

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

Beginner question here I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction. I need a listview of 'accounts' where each item will contain a textview, and a spinner to choose from a preset amount, so each item will be like so:

```
 ________________________
|TextView---------Spinner|
|________________________|
```

Here's what I have so far:

**activity_topup.xml** This is the main xml for the activity

```
<ListView 
         android:id="@+id/topup_accounts_listview" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@color/stq_grey"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
         android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"/>
```

And then in my java file **TopUpActivity.java**

```
String[] listAccounts = { "Acc1", "Acc2", "Acc3"};        
accountListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_item_accounts, R.id.accounts_list_tv, listAccounts);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.topup_accounts_listview);
        listView.setAdapter(accountListAdapter);
```

**listview_item_accounts.xml** contains the content of each item (a text view and spinner)

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/accounts_list_tv"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/accounts_list_amt_spinner"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_grey"
    style="@style/ListText" />

 <Spinner
    android:id="@id/accounts_list_amt_spinner"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:prompt="@string/topup_amt_prompt"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_blue"
    style="@style/ListText"  />
```

Am I on the right track?! The result is kind of correct but I can't quite figure out how to populate the spinners, all I can populate is the text views using this method I think. I added this to the java file in an attempt to populate the spinners too, but the spinners remain empty:

```
//Inflate the listview items
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_accounts, null);
//Get the spinner
amt = (Spinner)vi.findViewById(R.id.accounts_list_amt_spinner);
//Add the values to the spinner by setting this adapter
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.topup_amts, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
amt.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Here is the result](http://imageshack.us/a/img543/300/listviewm.png) (The spinners have the blue background): 

 

And when I click on one of the spinners they are empty, [I get this](http://imageshack.us/a/img138/2060/screenshot201303211259.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your sub views in it's parent.For example in `getView` of your adapter,you `iflate` your item(from listview_item_accounts.xml) as GroupView with name "item",then you have to find spinner in it:

```
Spinner amt = (Spinner)item.findViewById(R.id.accounts_list_amt_spinner);
```

If you use

```
Spinner amt = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accounts_list_amt_spinner);
```

you tried to find a view that it's id is equal to "R.id.accounts_list_amt_spinner" in content view,not in each item.

Comment: Okay I added some extra spinner code to the original post, it's not right yet but is it along the right lines at least?!

Comment: Thanks, I added a couple of images. It's good to know I am on the right track!

Comment: @hasanghaforian I think your answer is good and thank you very much for it, but I still get the same results, it's like I never even bothered populating the spinner values (the last chunk of code in the original post)...